# Надо ли избегать ведение разработки сайта прямо на продакшне?

Tags: wordpress, cms

Наверное да - надо. Но обо всём по порядку.

Присоединился к выполнению проекта, когда сайт был залит на хостинг и был готов процентов на 20. Сайт на WordPress. Ранее занимался только Front End, а Back End заниматься не приходилось.

Изначально не задумался где нужно вести разработку: на продакшне или локально? Легче оказалось присоединиться по ftp к продакшну. Схема разработки у меня выглядит таким образом: вношу изменение => нажимаю сохранить => среда разработки (PHPStorm) заливает изменённые файлы на хостинг.

В таком подходе я вижу проблему. Ведь иногда приходится удалять большие фрагменты страницы, менять адрес страницы и т.п. До тех пор, пока не настроено СЕО, пока на нём нету посетителей, то я могу себе позволить такие ситуации. А после - нет, поскольку это будет снижать конверсию, а это, очевидно, не нужно заказчику.

Как мне поступить в моей ситуации? Наверное, есть 2 группы решений:

1) Продолжать вести разработку на хостинге, но сделать так, чтобы посетителям сайта разработка была не видна и вообще никак не затрагивала.

2) Перенести разработку на локальное хранилище, а на продакшн заливать только крупные изменения. Тогда хочу узнать как это сделать? Все ли файлы надо переносить? Что можно почитать по этой теме?

В общем: **надо ли мне выходить из ситуации и, если да, то как?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Работа на локалке намного быстрее.
2. Если работа происходит в команде, то обязательно нужен гит
3. Если проект имеет несколько команд (например те, которые занимаются темой и те, которые занимаются плагинами), то нужно закрывать все возможные варианты изменения, кроме как деплоя через гит (репозиториев может быть много).

Но в целом, если вы работаете 1 и делаете сайты-визитки, то можете хоть через FileZill'у работать, никто не запрещает.

Answer (score 1):

Только 2 вариант. Вы же сами себе потом спасибо скажете.

Использовать можно git для деплоя файлов + WP DB migrate pro для базы данных. Базу данных изменять только на продакшене. А себе локально обновлять базу с лайв-сервера периодически.

вообще, для более сложных проектов вообще должна быть цепочка local-staging-live(production)

Answer (score 1):

Понятие "разработка" слишком широкое.
И какой-такой продакшн, если всего 20% готово?

Я работаю так:

Если это новый сайт, то можно и на рабочем домене делать. Но закрыть доступы из вне для посторонних.

При полной переделке существующего сайта я всегда делаю клон на др. домене. После того, как почти всё будет готово и проверено переношу на рабочий и доделывается то, что нельзя делать на клоне - отрывается индексация, проверяются связи с внешними сервисами и нек др. моменты.

При доработках так же делаю клон и что можно - делается на нём. Если за время работ на рабочем сайте не появляются новые данные (или их не проблема перенести в клон), то сайт просто клонируется на рабочий домен. Если же миграция не целесообразна или при этом можно потерять данные, которые появились за время работы, то наработки переносятся на продакшн "вручную" (напр если это изменения в теме, замена плагинов, настройки, оптимизация базы и тп).

И да миграция - только спец плагинами, (напр [Дупликатор](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)), но ни в коем случае не импортом базы! См [подробности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress).
Можно также использовать wp-cli.